# Discord.js -- message is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ayarlar = require('./ayarlar.json');

var prefix = ayarlar.prefix;

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Botun olan ${client.user.tag}sunucuya giriş yaptı ve artık aktif!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === 'salak aziz') {
  msg.channel.send('nerden bildin? helal olsun');
}
if (message.content === `${prefix}mal`) {
message.channel.send('Aziz Mert');
} else if (message.content === `${prefix}adam`) {
message.channel.send('Ata');
}

});
```

Im a beginner.

The error is 'ReferenceError: message is not defined' How can i fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You first named your variable `msg` and then started referring to it using `message`. Both names are fine, but you will need to use consistent names, otherwise the computer will not understand that they refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you defined the parameter of the `message` event as `msg` not `message`

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ayarlar = require('./ayarlar.json');

var prefix = ayarlar.prefix;

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Botun olan ${client.user.tag}sunucuya giriş yaptı ve artık aktif!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'salak aziz') {
  message.channel.send('nerden bildin? helal olsun');
}
if (message.content === `${prefix}mal`) {
message.channel.send('Aziz Mert');
} else if (message.content === `${prefix}adam`) {
message.channel.send('Ata');
}

});
```